# Using $invalid on form validation AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form with some angular validation:

```
<form ng-submit="vm.submit()" name="form" novalidate>
    <input class="form-control" name="userName" ng-model="vm.userName" required />
    <input class="form-control" name="pwd" ng-model="vm.pwd" required type="password" />
    <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid" type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

The problem I am having is that on page load, form.$invalid is registering as true if the username and password are auto completed by the browser. So, the page is loading with the form essentially filled out, but the Log In button is disabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `ng-disabled="form.$dirty && form.$invalid"`

Comment: form.$dirty also evaluates to true on page load if the fields are autocompleted.

Comment: what is invalid? what does `form.$error` contain?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know why form.$invalid evaluates as true when the fields are autocompleted. form.$error contains


{"required":[{"$viewValue":"","$modelValue":"","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"required":true},"$name":"pwd","$options":null}]}

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Does the same behavior manifest in different browsers?

Comment: Appears that it's only an issue in Chrome. Using Angular 1.3

Comment: The browser must have autocompleted the password field with an empty value.

Comment: The autocomplete values are correct.

Comment: @noclist, does it still not work with 1.4? If so, perhaps it's a Chrome-specific issue where the JS event is not fired, so Angular is unaware of the change

Answer (score 0):

If you autocomplete value for its correct, then you may tray force run `$digest` cycle. Of course  it's not clean solution))